# Possible validations in EditText with inputType:numberDecimal

Tags: android

I have an `EditText` in the following form:

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextNumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" />
```

Later I make `BigDecimal-Calculations` with the input, and realized that its possible to enter nothing or even a simple dot in that `EditText`. So I wrote following:

```
        EditText editTextNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);
        String number = String.valueOf(editTextNumber.getText());
        if (number.equals("") || number.equals(".")) {
            number = "1";
            editTextNumber.setText(number);
        }
```

Since I have overseen these two possible exceptions beforee I wonder if I have overseen another bug possibility in this code, and if there is a "cleaner" way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't handle any floats, `TextUtils.isDigitsOnly()` ([javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#isDigitsOnly(java.lang.CharSequence))) might be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I use this function. This does not account for international keypads that may use ',', rather than '.'.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(@Nullable String s)
{
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) return false;

    return s.matches("[-+]?\\d*\\.?\\d+");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

while processing data from editText or any other String which is populated from any other source is critical as you may never know what exactly is being feed to the String

you can write following code or customize it according to your requirement

```
private boolean isValidString(String text){

        if (text == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (text.trim().contentEquals("")) {
            return false;
        }

        if (text.trim().length() < 1) {
            return false;
        }

        if (text.trim().toLowerCase().contentEquals("null")) {
            return false;
        }

// you won't require following check for normal String , but as you would be dealing
// with numbers you may want to check that otherwise, Some surprises are 
// waiting for you, while doing some math with the numbers

if (!text.matches("[0-9]+(\\.[0-9][0-9]?)?")) {
            System.out.println("invalid: "+ text);
            return false;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Valid: "+ text);
        }
//


        return true;
    }
```

now assume this is the edittext you have

```
 EditText editTextNumber = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.editTextNumber);

if(isValidString(editTextNumber.getText().toString)){
```

> `your String validation is done so you can perform your relevant action here`

```
}
```